# How to find out what is in a Sitecore Package without installing it

Tags: packages

Once I have created a package and downloaded it to my system from Sitecore, is there any way to know what the package contains, maybe just path of those items.

I want to achieve this with out downloading the package into other environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can unzip the package. Inside that there will be package.zip. Unzip package.zip and inside that you will find installer folder, inside Installer folder open project file.

This project file is an xml file where you can see all the sources of package.

[image]

You can also see all the items in items folder. In this folder all the items from selected source are serialized. And can see all the files from files folder (if there are any files)

[image]

Comment: Additional tip: when unzipping, I recommend using 7zip. It easily navigates into zips contained within zips and makes it easy to open files up without actually having to unzip anything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use Package Designer to view the contents of the package too.

Open Package Designer
Open an existing package (either it is already present in your Packages or you can upload a new package)

[image]

Now from the window you can choose an existing package or a new package that can be uploaded. Suppose if you are creating the package from local or dev environment, while choosing existing package option, the package you had created will already be there.

[image]

Once you have selected the package and click Ok, there will be option to Preview. Click on the option and then click on Lookup. It will list all the items available in the package.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!!!